# Logo and Navigation Bar inline

Tags: html, css

I've been attempting to fix this issue for a few hours now, to no avail. I've browsed numerous different websites for answers, and i'm drawing a blank.

Im basically attempting to line both the logo, and the navigation bar links (the menu), together so they line up.
The navigation bar links should center vertically with the logo.

I can do it manually, by setting the exact pixels etc, but obviously this isn't much use. I have also tried having the logo as an li element, or it's own seperate div but i can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, alongside potentially a writeup as to where I am going wrong.

Thank you.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rLL36dz6/

HTML

```
    <img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" border="0 "width="7%"/>

    <ul class="nav_bar_links_ul">

        <li class="dropdown menulinks">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Game 1</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown menulinks">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Websites</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Website 1</a>
                <a href="#">Website 2</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown menulinks">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Meet the Team</a>
                <a href="#">About 2</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="twi">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kuCMtoG.png" border="0" width="2%" height="2%" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="twi">
            <a href="#"><img class="fb" src="http://i.imgur.com/vldeLpR.png" border="0" width="1.6%" height="1.6%" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

CSS can be found on fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your logo in a container:

```
 <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" />
 </div>
```

Set it to `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`.

Also ensure the image fits the container correctly.

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 7%;
}

.logo img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Wrap your nav in a container;

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="nav_bar_links_ul">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also set this to `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`.

Give it a width less than the image so that it can fit beside it in the container.

```
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 90%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/bmvyng1j/1/)

If you choose to align your menu to the right you can add

```
.nav {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am after. Thank you very much, I can see exactly what I was doing wrong as well for next time.

I'd give you a +rep or whatever but I am kind of new to stackoverflow, so will look into it!

Answer (score 1):

With the magic of `flexbox`, we can achieve something like this with just a few lines.

Is this it or did you need it tweaked some more?

```css
.nav_bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #00021a;
  width: 960px;
}
/* ALL NAVBAR GOES BELOW */

.all_navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.all_navigation{
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav_bar_links_ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav_bar_links_ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.nav_bar_links_ul li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.nav_bar_links_ul li,
a:hover {
  color: #2E9AFE;
}
.nav_bar_links_ul .menulinks li {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.nav_bar_links_ul .twi {
  display: inline;
}
.menulinks {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.twi:hover {
  color: #2E9AFE;
}
/* NAVIGATION DROP DOWN */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #2E9AFE;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <div class="all_navigation">

    <img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" border="0" width="60" height="auto" />

    <ul class="nav_bar_links_ul">

      <li class="dropdown menulinks">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Game 1</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown menulinks">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Websites</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Website 1</a>
          <a href="#">Website 2</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown menulinks">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Meet the Team</a>
          <a href="#">About 2</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="twi">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kuCMtoG.png" border="0" width="2%" height="2%" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="twi">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="fb" src="http://i.imgur.com/vldeLpR.png" border="0" width="1.6%" height="1.6%" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not really center the elements vertically. Increase the height of `.all_navigation` and you'll see that the menu entries stay at the top and the logo is stretched.

Comment: Thats essentially what I want, however it can't be stretched, and should work on different resolutions of screen.
This is essentially how I want it to look
[link](http://image.prntscr.com/image/b989860720874644b06610a76c1ca546.png)

Comment: Updated the snippet.

Comment: That is basically what I want yes. Is that dynamic in terms of page scaling etc? Not sure if that even makes sense

Comment: Should be, it depends on the rest of your styles. Flexbox is the mechanism the next version of Bootstrap is built upon.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice solution. @JBond4546 I hope you don't have to support old IEs.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `float: left` on the logo and give it a fixed width so that it doesn't span the whole width of container like a default block level element:

jsfiddle proof: https://jsfiddle.net/rLL36dz6/15/

Non-jsfiddle proof:

```css
.nav_bar {
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 background-color: #00021a;
 width: 960px;
}

/* ALL NAVBAR GOES BELOW */

.all_navigation li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

.nav_bar_links_ul li {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.nav_bar_links_ul li, a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.nav_bar_links_ul li, a:hover {
 color: #2E9AFE;
}

.nav_bar_links_ul .menulinks li { 
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.nav_bar_links_ul .twi {
 display: inline;
}

.menulinks {
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.twi:hover {
 color: #2E9AFE;
}

/* NAVIGATION DROP DOWN */

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 color: #2E9AFE;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* new */
.nav_bar {
  float: left;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">  
 <div class="all_navigation">
  
  <img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" border="0 "width="7%"/>
  
  <ul class="nav_bar_links_ul">
   
   <li class="dropdown menulinks">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Game 1</a>
    </div>
   </li>
    
   <li class="dropdown menulinks">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Websites</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Website 1</a>
     <a href="#">Website 2</a>
    </div>
   </li>
    
   <li class="dropdown menulinks">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Meet the Team</a>
     <a href="#">About 2</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   
   <li class="twi">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kuCMtoG.png" border="0" width="2%" height="2%" /></a>
   </li>
   <li class="twi">
    <a href="#"><img class="fb" src="http://i.imgur.com/vldeLpR.png" border="0" width="1.6%" height="1.6%" /></a>
   </li>
  </ul>  
 </div>
</div>
```

You could also simply put logo in `ul>li` and make it `inline-block` or `inline`.

You need to set paddings or vertical align to center things horizontally. I can't explain in detail gotta go yet; could clarify further tomorrow.

Comment: I did try the whole floating the image left, and fixing a width but caused a few problems.
The main being that the logo could no longer be seen, (Was no longer within the navigation bar)